# install.packages(...) fails on Windows 10

Tags: r, dplyr, windows-10, installation-package

I am trying to install the `dplyr` package from Visual Studio 2017. It has a dependency on `pillar`.

When I perform an install from the command line, I get:

```
> install.packages('pillar')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jérôme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
pillar  1.2.1  1.2.2             FALSE

installing the source package ‘pillar’

trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/pillar_1.2.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 64185 bytes (62 KB)
downloaded 62 KB

* installing *source* package 'pillar' ...
** package 'pillar' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Jirtme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pillar/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'pillar'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jérôme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/pillar'
```

There is a bogus conversion of `Jérôme Verstrynge` into `Jirtme Verstrynge`.

How can I work around this?

**More information**

When I perform Get-WinSystemLocale from Windows 10 PowerShell, I get:

```
LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2057             en-GB            English (United Kingdom)
```

Sys.getlocale() returns:

```
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252;
     LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252;
     LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252;
     LC_NUMERIC=C;
     LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252"
```

**Workaround**

I have uninstalled Microsoft R client and reinstalled it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/install-on-windows). The client is now on version 3.4.3.0.

The issue has disappeared for the package pillar, but it is coming back with a package called `dendextend` while trying to `install.packages('seriation')`.

The error is:

```
> install.packages('seriation') 
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Jérôme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘dendextend’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
dendextend  1.7.0  1.8.0             FALSE

trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/seriation_1.2-3.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1015954 bytes (992 KB)
downloaded 992 KB

package ‘seriation’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Temp\Rtmpi2lOd8\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘dendextend’

trying URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/dendextend_1.8.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1758392 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB

* installing *source* package 'dendextend' ...
** package 'dendextend' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") :
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Jirtme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dendextend/DESCRIPTION': No such file or directory
Error in file(file, if (append) "a" else "w") : 
  cannot open the connection
ERROR: installing package DESCRIPTION failed for package 'dendextend'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jérôme Verstrynge/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/dendextend'
In R CMD INSTALL

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Temp\Rtmpi2lOd8\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/MIE74D~1/RCLIEN~1/R_SERVER/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Jérôme Verstrynge\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Temp\Rtmpi2lOd8/downloaded_packages/dendextend_1.8.0.tar.gz' had status 1 
2: In utils::install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘dendextend’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

It seems there is an issue in `utils::install.packages(...)`

**Issue solved**

Apparently, on top of re-installing Microsoft R Client, the remaining issue was related to missing binary packages not available on CRAN repositories yet.

Comment: Offhand I would guess that you may need to get your R locales in line with your Windows 10 installation. See: `?Sys.setlocale`

Comment: @42- I think the locales are OK (see my addition in the question)

Comment: If you attempted to edit, then that edit did not "stick".

Comment: Ok, re, I have republished my edit @42-

Comment: Seems the codepage for 1252 (a Windows-specific feature) is doing something strange with your `Jérôme` inputs in the Visual Studio environment. I think ascribing this issue to R might not be entirely correct.

Comment: Visual Studio 10, Windows 10 Powershell, ... are all irrelevant in the sense that not a single line in the (copious) R documentation suggests them.  Use R and either install the binary, or buckle-up, install Rtools with the mingw-gcc needed to build from source and build from source.  There is no in-between.

Comment: The issue only happens with the pillar package. It's all fine with other packages. Code page 1252 knows characters with accents.

Comment: Would you mind editing the title of your question to make it more specific to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this has anything to do with the *pillar* package, but perhaps with the fact that this package is installed from source (unlike the default which is to install from binary). This problem will eventually resolve itself as the binary version of *pillar* 1.2.2 becomes available on your CRAN mirror (it's already there on CRAN and on https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/pillar/index.html).

What's the value of `getOption("repos")` on your system?

The mis-encoding of non-ASCII characters in this particular scenario feels like a problem which is best avoided by choosing an ASCII-only and space-free directory name for your home (e.g. `C:\Users\jverstry` instead of your current setting). To rule out a problem with Visual Studio, you could try installing the package from RGui or from the R terminal, please double-check that the installation path for the package is the same.

Comment: For R studio, I get: package ‘pillar’ is not available (for R version 3.3.3)

Comment: For RGui (which is on Microsoft R Open version 3.4), the installation works fine...

Comment: Binary packages are only available for the two most recent versions of R: 3.5 (released very recently) and 3.4. Can you upgrade your Visual Studio setup to at least R 3.4?

Comment: That's what I did and it solved the issue. Although I now have it with a package called dendextend.

Comment: dendextend has been updated on CRAN a few days ago, binaries for R 3.4 haven't been built yet. Should auto-resolve in a few days.

Comment: I confirm the issue is now solved (tried again today). See update in question for more information.